# How to get contain letter in c# like in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

In sql, i use this query to get contain letter:

```sql
select users_id, users_name, users_phone, users_address, users_email from dbo.tblUser
             where users_name like 'usersname%'
```

But when i use the same query in c#, i get this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '%'.'

query in c#:

```sql
select users_id, users_name, users_phone, users_address, users_email from dbo.tblUser
             where users_name like @usersname%
```

Comment: Those queries aren't the same; you have a literal string in one (`'usersname%'`) and a malformed variable name in the other (`@usersname%`). Presumably you meant `@usersname + '%'`?

Comment: You can add the % sign to the parameter's value in the c# code. Example: `param.Value = userNameVariable + "%";`

Comment: @Larnu I think it's basically a misunderstanding from OP of how parameters work. They are not interpolated directly into the query text. They are *bound* to the parameter name, and then fed in after the parsing and lexing stage of compilation. So they act as variables

Comment: *"I think it's basically a misunderstanding from OP of how parameters work"* And why I voted to close as a typographical error, @Charlieface .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are adding an unknown symbol in your query. There are no quotes around it and also no concatenation is used.

One way to fix that is to add the `%` character to the parameter's value in the c# code. Example:

```
param.Value = userNameVariable + "%";
```

```
WHERE users_name LIKE @usersname
```

Another option is to concatenate it in the query.

```
WHERE users_name LIKE @usersname + '%'
```

or

```
WHERE users_name LIKE CONCAT(@usersname, '%')
```